# Python:numpy - what is loc, scl, parameter?

Tags: python

`loc =` ....
`scl =` ...

`normdist = np.random.normal(loc = loc, scale = scl, size = 20)`

What purpose does loc, scl serve?

`sampledist = np.random.exponential(scale = parameter, size = sample_size)`

What does the parameter size represent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) does a pretty good job at explaning what those parameters mean. In short, for normal distribution, loc is a mean of the distribution and scale is a standard deviation. Size corresponds to the shape output. Example

```
np.random.normal(loc=1,scale=2,size=3)
Output: array([ 0.93646495, -0.1031504 ,  2.43463986])
```

And

```
np.random.normal(loc=1,scale=2,size=[2,2])
Output: array([[ 0.39330539,  2.22536236],
       [-1.25659788,  1.91092791]])
```

Comment: Maybe knowing why the parameters are named loc and scale would help understand the purpose of these? would you happen to know?